# what is the most accurate way to know if the visitor to a mobile webapp is unique?

Tags: android

I need to develop a webapp that needs to know the unique identifier (mac address, for example) of the smartphone that is using it. Most of the methods I'm looking at are cookie/IP based but this is not useful in my case scenario as I'm trying to match the use of a native Android app to the use of its counterpart webapp.

So, is this even possible? If it is, which technology should I use for the webapp development?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could leave a UUID cookie with the user. When they hop on the app, check the UUID against your list of previous visitors. If you find it, they are not unique.

Edit: by cookie, I mean you could just leave a UUID string file on the user's sd card or store it in a preference of the app.

Comment: Thanks, but the thing is... what happens if the user visits the webapp (the website) many times before even downloading the native app? How can I know that is the same user? I need to know the UUID from the website and I'm not sure if this is possible.

Comment: You can't still use a normal cookie for that? If they use the browser to view your site, they can still recieve cookies. Then use the cookie manager to find the needed cookie to retrieve your information.

Comment: I can use a normal cookie for that, but if you look at my question, I decided not to (or, better, "I prefer not to") because I don't think is reliable enough. User can always delete the cookies or use different browsers. So the question remains the same. Is there any way to get a unique identifier for a smartphone when navigating a webpage?

Comment: I understand that you don't want to use a cookie (for they can be deleted), but if the user deletes the cookie, they are asking to not have that connection to the site. If they don't want the connection, why force it on them? That is kinda Big Brotherish. As far as I know, the best you can do is poll OS and screen size, maybe browser. None of these will aid you in you UUID issue. The only other thing I can think of is Username and Password. And if that doesn't work for you then I have to ask what you are designing that requires such obfuscated information gathering.

Comment: Well, you can delete the cookies, temporal files or just use different browser not because my web, but because of a lot of other reasons. (Other webs you don't want to leave trace, bad behavior of the browser, whatever...) I don't think is obfuscated at all, is just a matter of statistics. I don't want to get the name of the user or even the android version he has I only want to know which is first, the web or the app. And the most accurate the answer is, the better. If I can't have an UUID, I will conform with the cookie, but that is not what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably the application is installed from the Android Market, so you can't match a site cookie passed in the download URL (or, doubtless, that's exactly what you'd do).

That being the case, can you use URL rewriting? Or at least insert a unique ID into each access to your website, doubtless corresponding to a cookie. Then, when the user downloads the application and runs it the first time it can access the Browser history and look for this unique ID, store it (if it exists) and include it with subsequent server requests.

```
int occasions=0;
        String sessionId = null;
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String urlVisited=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BookmarkColumns.URL));
            Log.d("Match",urlVisited);
            if (urlVisited.contains("www.mysite.com") && urlVisited.contains("MYUNIQUEID")) {
            //There's a unique ID. Trim it out of the query string.                 
                    sessionId=urlVisited.substring(urlVisited.indexOf("MYUNIQUEID")+10);
                    if (sessionId.indexOf('&')>-1) {
                        sessionId=sessionId.substring(0,sessionId.indexOf('&'));
                    }
                    occasions++;
                }
            }
            Log.d("Match","occasions="+occasions);
            if (sessionId!=null) {
                getSharedPreferences("com.mysite", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putString("SITEID", sessionId);
            }
```

This seems like a bit of a hack - possibly because it is - but it should work and I can't think of another sure way to link browser and custom client requests. Of course if the user cleans his history or cookies before downloading and running the application then the above will not work.

I hope that's of some help.

Comment: Thanks for the code and the effort. The thing is, as I said in the question, I want to skip the use of a cookie as I don't think it is reliable. But it looks like I will have no other chance as I can't find a proper way to identify with no error margin a smartphone.